# Averaging a pivot table column

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pivot table which is counting the number of instances of `pos` by date.  The code looks like:

```
pivot = Year1Data.reset_index()\
           .pivot_table(index='date', 
                        values=['pos'],
                         aggfunc=[len])
```

I'm using len to count the number of pos that occur each day.

I get the output:

```
              len
              pos
date             
2016-02-12  573.0
2016-03-05   15.0
2016-03-06  620.0
2016-03-08  495.0
2016-03-10  622.0
```

I am then trying to average the `pos` column by using :

```
average_number_of_positions =  pivot["pos"].mean()
```

but I get a keyerror:

```
KeyError: 'pos'
```

I've tried different things to make it work, but to no avail.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The column names of your pivot dataframe have two levels.

So something like this should work:

```
average_number_of_positions = pivot.loc[:,['len','pos']].mean()
```